# Which should I use in this sentence: a piece or apiece?

Tags: word-usage

I'm having some confusion regarding the use of "a piece" and "apiece" for a sentence I've written for a fiction piece. Have I used "apiece" to mean "each" correctly here?

Context: I want to convey that both A and B sent a team of two each.

> Both A and B would send a team of two **apiece** to the house where the girl was being kept. Each team would then discuss how to rescue the girl and act accordingly.

Comment: What did you find when you [looked it up](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apiece)?

Comment: Usage-wise, I think using "each" is far more common (AmE anyway).

Comment: I would use _each,_ but I wouldn't use it there: _A and B would **each** send a team of two to the house where the girl was being kept. Each team would then discuss how to rescue the girl and act accordingly._  (Note that I intentionally dropped _both_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Apiece" is the one that means "each", but it's not really necessary in your example because you already use "both".  I would normally use "apiece" if it's in any way *unclear* how many there are or how they are divided up.  If *both* teams send *a team of two* there is no ambiguity.

Here's a different example:

> In the game, each of the players first puts 10 "coins" **apiece** into the "pot".

meaning that, however many players there are, each contributes 10 coins.

Meanwhile "a piece" means a section, bit, or segment of some whole object:

> You can have **a piece** of pie after supper.